# Play framework not found value routesGenerator when running activator run

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to setup play framework but when running

```
activator run
```

I receive this error

```
/build.sbt:17: error: not found: value routesGenerator
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

I've searched for solutions with no luck, is there any incompatibility issue for play framework 2.3.9?

My environment is ubuntu 12.0.4 with java 1.7.0_21

Thank you.

Comment: `InjectedRoutesGenerator` is a setting in Play Framework 2.4 if you use dependency injection (see [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting#Dependency-Injection)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InjectedRoutesGenerator is from the Play 2.4.x

- [Play 2.4 Dependency Injection](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection)
- [Migration to the Play 2.4](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24)

Answer (score 5):

I know that you have accepted a correct answer but here's what will fix the issue:
You're missing this import: import play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys._